# How to insert subscript in LaTexDraw?

Tags: diagrams, subscripts

I wish to insert a simple vertex name like a1. All I want is to put 1 as subscript of a. I couldnot figure out how to do it in LaTexDraw.

Comment: You can not directly insert a subscript to a variable in LaTeXDraw. You should modify `pstricks` code obtained from LaTeXDraw. For example, LaTeXDraw gives `\rput(0.0603125,0.02890625){a}`, you can modify as `\rput(0.0603125,0.02890625){$a_1$}` when you insert it to your tex file.

Comment: @ferahfeza, What if I want to crop the image? Can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you insert a text, insert `$a_1$`. LaTeXDraw would still show you that the text is `$a_1$` but when you export the project as "`eps (latex) picture`" you will get your desired result. You can then use that eps figure.

Comment: Thanks, its the perfect answer that worked. I was exporting the project as pdf though :)